# How to use Symfony2 form elements individually?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

For example I would like to use ChoiceType in Twig by passing choices, selected value and options.

Something like..

```
{{ render_select(choices, selected) }}
```

or

```
{{ render_choices(choices, selected, {'expanded': true, 'multiple': true}) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do it in Twig. The best practice is to creare a Form Class (Type) and define there this type of behaviour.

Example:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('task')
           ->add('dueDate', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
           ->add('active', 'choiche', array(
               'choices'   => array('0' => 'Deactive', '1' => 'Active'),
               'required'  => true,
               )
           )
           ->add('save', 'submit');
   }

   public function getName()
   {
       return 'task';
   }
}
```

More info in the [Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

If you want to do it anyway, you should do it like this:

```
{{ form(form.formField, {'expanded': true, 'multiple': true, 'choices': {'0': 'Zero', '1': 'One'}}) }}
```

As you can see, it's really not easy...

Comment: I'm trying to do Magento-like "product custom options" management for an entity.

Comment: So your FormType class should extend the Magento Form class that you need.

Comment: Thank you. I had wrong approach to this problem. I actually found solution by using Form Collections (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and doing it the right way.